# MS-Access library for performing many kinds of DDL operations on a database (to facilitate application version upgrades)?

Tags: ms-access

I need a library to facilitate numerous DDL actions on an MS Access database in order to perform product upgrades.

For example, if I am shipping a version 3.0 upgrade to a customer who is currently running 1.0, I need to apply multiple DDL actions to bring their database schema inline with the current version shipping.

So, this could consist of adding new tables, columns, performing insert/update queries, etc.

Of course one can write all this by hand, but the various most common actions *could* be encapsulated into a nice user-friendly library that makes writing (as well as reading) these upgrade scripts much nicer.

Has anyone encountered such a library (or have even a half decent one sitting around in one of your projects that you'd be willing to share?)

*(Alternatively, is there a reasonably priced commercial product that I can point at 2 different versions, and have it generate an upgrade script?)*

Comment: It sound like you are looking in the wrong direction. You ship v3 and then import from v1, not the other way round.

Comment: @Remou - yes I suppose that is one way of doing it, but I've never seen anyone do it that way.  And in the scenario where you are dealing with large (# rows & tables) databases with small schema changes (adding a few columns) that is the worst way to do it.  In my current scenario I definitely want to modify the schema in the existing database.

Comment: Take a look at this article right here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077561/create-and-update-programmatically-database-structure